# Quais são as Boas práticas para Ler dados do Firebase e Inserir nas Activitys?

Tags: android, firebase

Estou conseguindo **Inserir e Recuperar os dados do Firebase**...
Porém eu **não sei** como passo as informações obtidas para alguns EditTexts, TextViews em **diversas classes..**

**Perguntas:**

> **Quais são as boas práticas para passar informações em diversas
>   Activity com o Firebase?**
>
> **Quais são as boas práticas para criar uma Classe Java somente para o
>   Firebase e dinamizar o código, para que sirva para a maioria das
>   classes?**

**MainActivity.class**

```
package com.hotelaria.neoris.checkincheckout.activitys;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.hotelaria.neoris.checkincheckout.R;
import com.hotelaria.neoris.checkincheckout.models.objects.Firebase;
import com.hotelaria.neoris.checkincheckout.models.objects.User;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.onClickButtonGoToBookingActivity();
    }

    public void onClickButtonGoToBookingActivity(){
        Button btnBookingActivity = findViewById(R.id.buttonBooking);
        btnBookingActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BookingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Firebase.class**

```
package com.hotelaria.neoris.checkincheckout.models.objects;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.hotelaria.neoris.checkincheckout.activitys.MainActivity;


public class Firebase {

    private final FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private final FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private final DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    public void writeNewUser(final Activity activity, final String email, final String password){
        this.mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            User user = new User();
                            user.setUsername(email);
                            user.setPassword(password);

                            mDatabaseReference.child("usr/" + mFirebaseAuth.getUid()).setValue(user);

                            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),"SUCESSO, CONTA CADASTRADA!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),"OPS ACONTECEU ALGUM ERRO...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public void signInUser(final Activity activity, String email, String password){
        this.mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),"SUCESSO...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    activity.getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    queryUserData();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),"OPS ACONTECEU ALGUM ERRO...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void queryUserData(){
        String userUid = this.mFirebaseAuth.getUid();
        Query queryUser = this.mDatabaseReference.child("usr").orderByKey().equalTo(userUid);

        queryUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            MainActivity mMainActivity = new MainActivity();

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User mDataUser = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                Log.w("onCancelled", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                // ...
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Possui vários cursos gratuitos na internet de como utilizar o Firebase, eu [respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/302465/62637) uma pergunta sua a pouco tempo atrás e não foi nem verificado e ajustado o código com o uso dos botões. Recomendo o [guia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) do firebase mesmo

Comment: @Gaspar me manda o link da pergunta, pois eu não estou achando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Quais são as boas práticas para criar uma Classe Java somente para o
>   Firebase e dinamizar o código, para que sirva para a maioria das
>   classes?

Eu utilizo esta classe para puxar a referência do `DatabaseReference` e do `FirebaseAuth`

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public final class FirebaseConfig {

    private static DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private static FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    public static DatabaseReference getFirebaseReference() {
        if (databaseReference == null) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            databaseReference.keepSynced(true);
        }
        return databaseReference;
    }

    public static FirebaseAuth getFirebaseAuth() {
        if (firebaseAuth == null) {
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        }
        return firebaseAuth;
    }

}
```

Na activity se precisar puxar a referência dos usuários eu utilizo:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseConfig.getFirebaseReference().child("users");
```

O mesmo serve para a autenticação:

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseConfig.getFirebaseAuth();
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(...
```

Comment: você não cria nenhum método na class do Firebase, para busca de dados? Isto você faz "manualmente" dentro da classe da Activity é isto? Beleza, eu consigo inserir e pegar as informações, mas como eu faço para inserir um resultado por exemplo em um EditText, levando em consideração que existem diversas Activitys que conterá a mesma informação.

Comment: Quando eu possuo esta situação eu crio uma classe helper de um modelo de dados (por exemplo usuários = UsuarioHelper.class) e dentro desta classe eu coloco uma **alteração** no _firebase_, a **busca** do _firebase_ é assíncrona, então não é muito legal criar uma classe dinâmica para buscar um dado naquele dado instante e continuar o código como os demais bancos de dados. Então quando é uma busca no banco do firebase eu crio cada activity um listener e removo o listener no `onDestroy` da activity. Então se você possui uma lista de contatos por exemplo, um usuário mudou o nome, vai mudar automat

Comment: Teve um caso que aconteceu comigo que estava exigindo muito recurso do celular buscar e recuperar dados do _Firebase_ por causa desta situação em específico de **um valor** ser utilizado por VÁRIAS ACTIVITIES, foi então que eu fiz uma _gambiarra_ de colocar um listener num `Service` em **um dado específico** para cada usuário, então o valor sempre estava lá pra recuperar caso alterasse, iria alterar automaticamente

Comment: show de bola, entendi.. Você poderia me dar um exemplo deste Helper na sua resposta acima? É essa parte faz referencia a minha pergunta também, onde tenho dúvida.

Comment: No caso ocorrido acima tinha um valor na variável _status_ dentro de _Users_ que determinada situação esse _status_ era "0", outra situação era "1", então coloquei um listener no `Service` que ficava sempre escutando a alteração em `databaseReference.child("users").child("idUser").child("status");` e no `onDataChange` do listener o valor mudava para todas as outras _activities_

Comment: Sim, esta classe eu uso para [ActivationService.class](https://pastebin.com/mKDnQwHe), e esta para [UserHelper.class](https://pastebin.com/uvNRAejL), fui autor dessa besteirada toda :D use como quiser